# Swift 4 убрать верхний бар

Tags: swift, navigation

Есть такая проблема. Отображаю ViewController таким способом. Необходимо убрать верхний бар с кнопкой **Back**. Как это возможно сделать?
Пробовал такие варианты...

**self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true**

**self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1**

```
func navToRecord(){
    
    let mainViewController = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NQTPrivateOfficeViewController") as! NQTPrivateOfficeViewController
    let leftViewController = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NQTLeftViewController") as! NQTLeftViewController

    let nc = odrexNavigation(rootViewController: mainViewController)

    let slideMenuController = EVTSlideMenuController(mainViewController: nc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)
    slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    mainViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Завершить", comment: "finishOdrex"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
    nav.pushViewController(slideMenuController, animated: true)

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()


}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем расширение для UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideNavigationBar() {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }

    func showNavigationBar() {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Используем во ViewController:

Для скрытия

```
self.hideNavigationBar()
```

Для показа

```
self.showNavigationBar()
```

Но, не забываем, что у всех последующих контроллеров которые находятся в навигационном стеке navigationBar тоже скроется, поэтому если необходимо скрывать бар только в определенном контроллере, то для ближайших двух в методе контроллера `viewWillApper` прописываем `self.showNavigationBar()`

Answer (score 0):

См. документацию:

```
open var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool
```

Использованние:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

---

Xcode 13 Swift 5.5

Comment: здесь принято общаться на русском языке. исправьте ваш ответ, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]